# Hibernate filter does not apply for Spring MVC controller

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, rest, spring-mvc

I am trying to filter collection during login process.
I have declared a “@FilterDef” on the paren entity:

```
@FilterDef(name = "organizationMemberFilter", parameters = @ParamDef(name = "MemberIdParam", type = "integer"))
```

And set it on the child property:

```
@JsonIgnore
@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.MERGE, orphanRemoval = true)
@LazyCollection(LazyCollectionOption.EXTRA)
@JoinColumn(name = "ORG_ID", referencedColumnName = "ID")
@OrderColumn(name = "ID")
@Filter(name = "organizationMemberFilter", condition = "id = :MemberIdParam")
private Set<Member> members = new HashSet<Member>();
```

at the controller I am using this filter:

```
@RequestMapping("/login/{id}/{pass}")
public Feedback login(HttpServletRequest request, @PathVariable("id") String id,
        @PathVariable("pass") String password, HttpServletResponse res) {
    Feedback feedback = new Feedback();
    DataSource ds = (DataSource) context.getBean("dataSource");
    .
    .
    .
        if (mem.getType().equals("admin")) {
            // Get all members
            session.disableFilter("organizationMemberFilter");
        } else {
            //Filter members
            Filter filter1 = session.enableFilter("organizationMemberFilter");
            filter1.setParameter("MemberIdParam", mem.getId());
        }               
        org = (Organization)session.get(Organization.class,orgid);

        logger.debug("num of members: " + org.getMembers().size());

        feedback.getData().put("entity", org);
        feedback.setSuccess();
    } 
    return feedback;
}
```

The problem is that the controller rever back to the client before the filter is applied!
If I put a breakpoint in the code and let the filter complete I can see that thee result is properly filtered.

How do I make sure that the controller will not return until filter was applied on the collection?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, foud the issue...
Had to initialize the filtered collection:

```
Hibernate.initialize(org.getMembers());
```